# Regex for string that can be composed by multiple words [java]

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression in Java for a string that can be composed by multiple words (or just one). The word(s) inside the string may include digits inside or at the end of them.

Something like:

> hello byebye4 carrot

or just:

> apple4

How can I do this?

Comment: I write some examples of string in the post: Something like: "hello byebye4 carrot", or just "apple4".

Comment: any word is accepted (it's for a kind of editor-like program)

Comment: You gotta write some code or it will never get done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String regex = "([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\s+)+";
```

Comment: if you want it to capture single words as well, you should change one character in this regex: `"([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\s*)+"` (the "+" before the \\s to "*").

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+
```

to match a single word.